# Modifying spring LocalContainerEntityManageFactoryBean at runtime to change Hibernate dialect

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

We are using spring LocalContainerEntityManageFactoryBean .The problem is that we have to connect different databases in multitenancy environment.Need to figure out a way through which we can change LocalcontainerEntityMangerFactory bean jpa property for dialect at runtime without restart

Answer (score 0):

Instead what you should do is initialize two different `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` instances with their appropriate dialects and then simply reference the correct `EntityManager` based on what database your code should interact with.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dialect1PersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager1;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "dialect2PersistenceUnit")
private EntityManager entityManager2;
```

If things must be truly dynamic, you have a few options.

If you intend to only work with a single data source at a time, you could setup your database such that it is based on `AbstractRoutingDataSource` and set a thread local value that determines which persistence context to use.  Typically you'd set the thread local value in a service tier wrapper before you invoke the transaction management aspect.

Another alternative would be to inject an `EntityManagerFactory` rather than the `EntityManager` and construct your own `EntityManager` on the fly, as shown below:

```
Map props = new HashMap();
props.put( "org.hibernate.dialect", YourDialectClass.class.getName() );

EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager( props );
```

HTH.

Comment: I cannot not go with this approach because our application points to H2  as default datasource, We can configure the tenants(databases) dynamically and can be oracle,Mysql,MSSQl .At runtime we have to decide the dialects

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Naros. We have to go with approach of creating entitymanager dynamically.Other solution not worked.